# Odd results when running similar queries in Postgres

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I am having this issue where my database is causing the CPU usage of our db server to hit 100% on a particular query. The query has two different where clauses and does not work, but when I delete either of the where clauses, the query returns quickly. The query i am trying to run is the following. This query references two tables in the database, asset_asset and asset_assetclassification. asset_asset has 1.8 million rows and asset_assetclassification has 7k rows.

```
select count(1) from asset_asset INNER JOIN "asset_assetclassification" ON ("asset_asset"."classification_id" = "asset_assetclassification"."id") WHERE ("asset_assetclassification"."company_id" = 1 AND "asset_asset"."deleted_at" IS NULL);
```

Here is a screenshot of the query plan for this query.

```
 Aggregate  (cost=1684.74..1684.75 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=382010.081..382010.084 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(1)
   Buffers: shared hit=36981708
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=381.65..1684.64 rows=41 width=0) (actual time=367.455..381892.265 rows=1836169 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=36981708
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.asset_assetclassification  (cost=4.30..15.73 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.440..8.577 rows=7305 loops=1)
               Output: asset_assetclassification.id, asset_assetclassification.name, asset_assetclassification.image, asset_assetclassification.instance_id, asset_assetclassification.template_id, asset_
assetclassification.company_id, asset_assetclassification.ecn, asset_assetclassification.ecn_status, asset_assetclassification.ecr, asset_assetclassification.ecr_status, asset_assetclassification.snapsh
ot_date, asset_assetclassification.snapshot_model_id, asset_assetclassification.parent_id, asset_assetclassification.unique_field, asset_assetclassification.serial_format, asset_assetclassification.seri
al_help_text, asset_assetclassification.overlam_proof_id, asset_assetclassification.proof_id, asset_assetclassification.eci_code, asset_assetclassification.construct_group_id, asset_assetclassification.
snapshot_version, asset_assetclassification.status_note, asset_assetclassification.asssetplatform_id, asset_assetclassification.sets, asset_assetclassification.change_reason, asset_assetclassification.g
enerated_marking_spec, asset_assetclassification.serial_prefix, asset_assetclassification.tagging_image, asset_assetclassification.packaging_label_config_id, asset_assetclassification.pdf_file_name, ass
et_assetclassification.is_being_edited, asset_assetclassification.ecn_status_pre_on_hold, asset_assetclassification.ecr_status_pre_on_hold, asset_assetclassification.internal_serial_rules, asset_assetcl
assification.email_activity_email, asset_assetclassification.email_activity_name, asset_assetclassification.custom_data
               Recheck Cond: (asset_assetclassification.company_id = 1)
               Heap Blocks: exact=419
               Buffers: shared hit=510
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on asset_assetclassificatio_company_id_template_id_e_809bdeb8_uniq  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.401..0.401 rows=7305 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (asset_assetclassification.company_id = 1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=91
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.asset_asset  (cost=377.36..555.84 rows=46 width=4) (actual time=52.067..52.116 rows=251 loops=7305)
               Output: asset_asset.classification_id
               Recheck Cond: ((asset_asset.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (asset_asset.classification_id = asset_assetclassification.id))
               Heap Blocks: exact=143442
               Buffers: shared hit=36981198
               ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=377.36..377.36 rows=46 width=0) (actual time=51.999..51.999 rows=0 loops=7305)
                     Buffers: shared hit=36837756
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on asset_asset_deleted_at_db53c84c  (cost=0.00..173.40 rows=9196 width=0) (actual time=51.341..51.341 rows=1836169 loops=7305)
                           Index Cond: (asset_asset.deleted_at IS NULL)
                           Buffers: shared hit=36809895
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on asset_asset_classification_id_02396f18  (cost=0.00..201.40 rows=9196 width=0) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=252 loops=7305)
                           Index Cond: (asset_asset.classification_id = asset_assetclassification.id)
                           Buffers: shared hit=27861
 Planning Time: 0.255 ms
 Execution Time: 382010.270 ms
(28 rows)
```

And if i run this

```
select count(1) from asset_asset INNER JOIN "asset_assetclassification" ON ("asset_asset"."classification_id" = "asset_assetclassification"."id") WHERE ("asset_assetclassification"."company_id" = 1);
```

and here is a screenshot of the query plan for this query

```
 Aggregate  (cost=14072.34..14072.35 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=508.861..508.864 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(1)
   Buffers: shared hit=77728
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.73..14051.69 rows=8260 width=0) (actual time=0.466..401.478 rows=1839134 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=77728
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.asset_assetclassification  (cost=4.30..15.73 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.438..1.582 rows=7305 loops=1)
               Output: asset_assetclassification.id, asset_assetclassification.name, asset_assetclassification.image, asset_assetclassification.instance_id, asset_assetclassification.template_id, asset_
assetclassification.company_id, asset_assetclassification.ecn, asset_assetclassification.ecn_status, asset_assetclassification.ecr, asset_assetclassification.ecr_status, asset_assetclassification.snapsh
ot_date, asset_assetclassification.snapshot_model_id, asset_assetclassification.parent_id, asset_assetclassification.unique_field, asset_assetclassification.serial_format, asset_assetclassification.seri
al_help_text, asset_assetclassification.overlam_proof_id, asset_assetclassification.proof_id, asset_assetclassification.eci_code, asset_assetclassification.construct_group_id, asset_assetclassification.
snapshot_version, asset_assetclassification.status_note, asset_assetclassification.asssetplatform_id, asset_assetclassification.sets, asset_assetclassification.change_reason, asset_assetclassification.g
enerated_marking_spec, asset_assetclassification.serial_prefix, asset_assetclassification.tagging_image, asset_assetclassification.packaging_label_config_id, asset_assetclassification.pdf_file_name, ass
et_assetclassification.is_being_edited, asset_assetclassification.ecn_status_pre_on_hold, asset_assetclassification.ecr_status_pre_on_hold, asset_assetclassification.internal_serial_rules, asset_assetcl
assification.email_activity_email, asset_assetclassification.email_activity_name, asset_assetclassification.custom_data
               Recheck Cond: (asset_assetclassification.company_id = 1)
               Heap Blocks: exact=419
               Buffers: shared hit=510
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on asset_assetclassificatio_company_id_template_id_e_809bdeb8_uniq  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.398..0.398 rows=7305 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (asset_assetclassification.company_id = 1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=91
         ->  Index Only Scan using asset_asset_classification_id_02396f18 on public.asset_asset  (cost=0.43..4586.69 rows=9196 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.033 rows=252 loops=7305)
               Output: asset_asset.classification_id
               Index Cond: (asset_asset.classification_id = asset_assetclassification.id)
               Heap Fetches: 301998
               Buffers: shared hit=77218
 Planning Time: 1.152 ms
 Execution Time: 508.979 ms
(20 rows)
```

or this

```
select count(1) from asset_asset INNER JOIN "asset_assetclassification" ON ("asset_asset"."classification_id" = "asset_assetclassification"."id") WHERE ("asset_asset"."deleted_at" IS NULL);
```

the query works perfectly fine. Note: the original query was generated by Django.

Any ideas about whats going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't "run out" of CPU. I assume you mean it is slower than you would like? Nobody can advise you on a performance issue like this without seeing the query plan and knowing something about the sizes of the tables involved and the distribution of their values.

Comment: Sorry for the missing info, I have edited the post to include screenshots of the query plans. And also added the number of the rows in each of the relevant tables.

Comment: Please update the post with the results of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)` as text, not an image. Make sure that `ANALYZE` has been run on the tables so that the optimizer is working with current statistics. From the explain plans you've posted, it looks like the statistics might be out of date.

Comment: @JohnH I have updated the explain plans. Please let me know if i can provide anymore info.

Comment: Removing the expression `AND "asset_asset"."deleted_at" IS NULL` from the first query substantially alters the amount of work that has to be done to resolve the result set. Although the text of the two queries is nearly identical, they are not similar from an execution standpoint. Nearly all of the time in the first query is spent performing the bitmap index scan on asset_asset_deleted_at_db53c84c and heap scan on asset_asset (7305 loops each with an average time of 51ms per loop).